# Better Alternative to 'keyup' Event

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete, mootools

I have an input text box which autofills via AJAX using this [Autocompleter Plugin](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/) for Mootools.

I'm currently using the '**keyup**' event to fetch the results via AJAX. *It works but I feel like it's a bit clunky at best since every keyboard press results into an AJAX request.*

I would prefer to have to make only **ONE** AJAX request once the user finishes typing like after the user pauses for a bit.

I've tried the '**change**' event but it was worse, I had to click away from the input text box just to make the AJAX request and then click on the input text box again just to have the 'onComplete' fire up.

Here's my code:

```
input.addEvent('keyup', function(e) {
    new Autocompleter.Request.JSON(input.getProperty('id'), url, {
        'postVar': 'search',
        'maxChoices': 6,
        'overflow': false,
        'selectMode': 'pick',
        'delay': 100,
        'forceSelect': false,
        onRequest: function() {
            // do nothing
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

I hope you guys understand my problem here.

Thanks!

Comment: what @sergio said is the right approach. debounce - also you can introduce key lookup cache as a small hashmap so save repeated calls for strings you've already queried.

Answer (score 1):

Change the option `'delay': 100,` to a higher number.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Krumia yes it does. The user is using a Autocomplete plugin that has a option `delay` for delaying the plugin until the typing is done. Also for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206436/better-alternative-to-keyup-event/30251724?noredirect=1#comment48561562_30207610

Comment: Please add these information to the answer, and an explanation. The reference you provided is the same question. Are you sure you post the right link?

Comment: @Krumia it is the right link. Its on a deleted post and only 10K users can see. There the author or the question refers that as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do the on keypress function then freeze the function for some seconds as you wanted

Code:

```
input.addEvent('keyup', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        new Autocompleter.Request.JSON(input.getProperty('id'), url, {
            'postVar': 'search',
            maxChoices: 6,
            overflow :false,
            'selectMode': 'pick',
            delay : 100,
            forceSelect:false,
            onRequest: function() {
                // do nothing
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
    },2000); //1000 = 1sec
});
```

Hope it solves your problem as you said in your question "I would prefer to have to make only ONE AJAX request once the user finishes typing like after the user pauses for a bit."

For more just comment.

Thanks...